# Remove whitespace between strings for all browsers?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

Anyone know how to remove white space between strings for all browsers? This works in everything but IE7. Basically all the li's text is used to reference div's class to show them. Some li's text has spaces some do not.

SCRIPT

```
$('li.' + $(this).text().replace(/&nbsp;/g, "-")).toggle(true);
```

HTML

```
<ul>
<li class="button" id="sun">sun&nbsp;protective&nbsp;clothing</li>
<li class="button" id="lawn">lawn&nbsp;games</li>
<li class="button" id="stuff">stuff</li>
</ul>

<div class="sun-protective-clothing"></div>
<div class="lawn-games"></div>
<div class="stuff"></div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show an example? i'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for your inquiry. I updated the text above to be more clear on the objective.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? The element "li.sun-protective-clothing" doesn't exist, so nothing is going to happen.

Comment: The text within the li is used to reference a class of a DIV element. Example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the unicode equivalent of `&nbsp` = `u00a0`

Now works great in IE7 too! :)

### [example DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/XK3CF/)

```
$('li').text(function (i, v) {
    return v.replace(/\u00a0/g,'-');
});
```

Comment: I'll try it for the future and thanks! I did another way and just used the first letter of the text instead of replacing the white spaces. :P

Answer (score 1):

Try using `/\s*/g` as your pattern instead of an actual space. (The \s is used for space character(s) in regex). i.e.

```
$('li.' + $(this).text().replace(/\s*/g, "-")).toggle(true);
```

I assume you're referencing the text of the `<LI>` to refer to the class of the `<DIV>` element, and want the hyphens to be inserted.

Comment: exactly, but not the ID of the div but the CLASS.

Comment: @Buildingbrick: Indeed, I slipped and said ID. But using the `\s` in place of an actual space should solve your issue(s).

Comment: @Buildingbrick: Do you get any script errors? Anything from the debugger letting you know an issue? Try singling out the code as best you can (isolate). e.g. does a simple `var foo = 'hello world'; alert(foo.replace(/\s*/g,'-'));` echo the desired result?

Comment: What about using a non-breaking space for the spaces in the links? That would be something all browsers can interpret.

Comment: in IE7 this puts dashes before and after all the characters

Comment: @Buildingbrick: Sorry, change it to `\s+` (use the `+` quantifier, and not the `*`)

Comment: I will try it anyways but I actually just by passing the whole replace white spaces and just used the first word instead which was much easier for me and the browsers to do. Thanks for your effort.